# Retrieving data from SQL Server with a stored procedure with ASP.net and c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a form and I want to retrieve data from a sql table and show it in the form's fields depending on the `?id` I enter in the url, but I always get this error:

> Procedure or function 'GetAppForm' expects parameter '@id', which was
>   not supplied.

Note: `GetAppForm` is the stored procedure.

Here's my code, please help me:

```
try
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
    {
        sqlConn.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetAppForm", sqlConn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter id = cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);                    
            id.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            id.Value = Request.QueryString["id"];

            SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                OwnerField.Text = dataReader["Owner"].ToString();
                OdBookNoField.Text = dataReader["OD"].ToString();
                PdLocField.Text = dataReader["pd"].ToString();
                StatementNoField.Text = dataReader["Statmnt"].ToString();
                ApplicationNoField.Text = dataReader["AppNo"].ToString();
                AppDateField.Text = dataReader["AppDate"].ToString();
                areaField.Text = dataReader["Area"].ToString();
                areaNoField.Text = dataReader["AreaNo"].ToString();
                blockNoField.Text = dataReader["BlockNo"].ToString();
                streetNoField.Text = dataReader["StreetNo"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("No Connection!!");
}
finally
{
    sqlConn.Close();
}
```

Comment: You haven't assigned any values to @id, pass the value to parameter then it will work. you can do following : int id=////some value;      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
```

to

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot to negate the `String.IsNullOrEmpty` condition:

```
 try
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
            {
```

Please note, your code is prone to injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
try
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
                {
                    sqlConn.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetAppForm", sqlConn))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Request.QueryString["id"]);                       
                        SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                        //SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
                        while (dataReader.Read())
                        {
                            OwnerField.Text = dataReader["Owner"].ToString();
                            OdBookNoField.Text = dataReader["OD"].ToString();
                            PdLocField.Text = dataReader["pd"].ToString();
                            StatementNoField.Text = dataReader["Statmnt"].ToString();
                            ApplicationNoField.Text = dataReader["AppNo"].ToString();
                            AppDateField.Text = dataReader["AppDate"].ToString();
                            areaField.Text = dataReader["Area"].ToString();
                            areaNoField.Text = dataReader["AreaNo"].ToString();
                            blockNoField.Text = dataReader["BlockNo"].ToString();
                            streetNoField.Text = dataReader["StreetNo"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("No Connection!!");
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlConn.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Thank you so much it is easy, I'm beginner :p